# How to use CSS Transition on click of input element ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group, react-animations

I am new to ReactJS and have never used any animations in React yet with CSS. 
I am trying to transition the width of an input on focus using CSS and it's not working out. 
Below is my JSX & CSS code

```
<div className={classes.SearchboxInput}>
   <input type="text" className="rq-form-element pickup-location" placeholder="Pickup Location" />
</div>
-------
.SearchboxInput input{
   background: transparent;
   border: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
   padding: 6px;
   width: 200px;
   margin-left: 11px;
   -webkit-transition: width 2s;
   transition: width 2s;
}
.SearchboxInput input[type=text]:focus {
   width:250px;
}
```

What happens on click is that it switches the width from 200 to 250 in 2 seconds WITHOUT transition appearing. From a little research, I found out that sometimes when elements need to rerender (Correct me if I am wrong), the transitions do not work and for this something such as CSSTransition from 'react-transition-group' library could be useful. I imported the library and my code looks like this now

```
<div className={classes.SearchboxInput}>
     <CSSTransition
        classNames = "pickup-location"
        in = {true}
        timeout = {200}>
                <input type="text" className="rq-form-element pickup-location" placeholder="Pickup Location" />
     </CSSTransition>
</div>
```

But when I go to console to see what parameters change for the CssTransition element on click of an input - I see that none of them changes (such as appear, enter, exit ...)

I could not find any useful demos on how to make this work and would appreciate a lot if anyone can help me with a similar example with JSFiddle or some kind of an explanation.

My main question here is how to transition the width/height of an input element on click in ReactJS if an element needs to rerender?

Comment: I recommend that you use `ref` instead of state change to perform this kind of effect especially on inputs.

Comment: @Lhew - Can you let me know where I can find more information about that - would you have any demos to show me an example?

Comment: Hey, i've done an example for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-napier-21w5h

Answer (score 0):

There are two different technologies appear in this question.

1. CSS + HTML. They work without React, just because browser supports rendering HTML. As `transition` is CSS prop, it will work without React at all. So it's no need to do re-rendering on transition. Browser will do 
   everything required.

   You have working code, but seems that you're using incorrect class name for `<div>` element. Use text string as `className` prop and code will work

   ```
   <div className="SearchboxInput">
     <input
       type="text"
       className="rq-form-element pickup-location"
       placeholder="Pickup Location"
     />
   </div>
   ```

   Here is [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/csstransition-561mm).
2. `CSSTransition` is completely different technology. It changes class names of wrapped component. To make smooth animation you should have specific class names with `-enter`, `-enter-active` and `-enter-done` suffixes. Animation is started when `in` prop is set to `true`, so this prop should be held in state.

   Here is [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/csstransitioncomponent-o9dey)

For you task I suggest to use first method with pure CSS.